# nokogiri multiple elements from xml to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have an XML news feed I want to grab stories out of, along with a few elements from each story.
The [the original xml](http://pastie.org/3490818) is here and This is an example of each story.

```
<news:NewsResult>
        <news:Title>Essex Police/Fire</news:Title>
        <news:Url>http://www.gloucestertimes.com/local/x2118804357/Essex-Police-Fire</news:Url>
        <news:Source>Gloucester Daily Times</news:Source>
        <news:Snippet>ESSEX — An attempt to serve a summons to a Piper Lane resident was thwarted at 2:25 p.m. Monday when police discovered that the person no longer lives at that address. Alarms were set off in error on Belcher Street at 3:12 p.m. Monday, on Main Street at ...</news:Snippet>
```

So far I have code like this:

```
def xml2Var(xmlin)
  #Parse received XML with Nokogiri
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(xmlin)

  #Remove  namespaces  
  doc.remove_namespaces!

  #print dat ish?  
# p p doc

#extract values.
  title = doc.xpath("//Title")
  snippet = doc.xpath("//Snippet")
  url = doc.xpath("//Url")
  source = doc.xpath("//Source")
```

I want to put these values into an array for each story. Then, add each story into a stories array so that I can then display it in my Rails app.
I kind-of managed to do this, but then could not display each story, and each story's attributes. I think my use of Xpath is wrong?

Comment: Without seeing the XML or some XPath that shows how to retrieve a single `story`, we can't possible help you there.

Comment: Please summarize the XML into a smaller sample that will still show the problem you want to fix, and append it to your question by reediting it. Having the link does us very little good if it breaks. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To put the stories into arrays you would do something like:

```
doc.css("NewsResult").map{|nr| [nr.at('Title'),nr.at('Snippet'),nr.at('Url'),nr.at('Source')].map(&:text)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given four arrays of values, as you have, you *could* interleave them like so:

```
titles   = %w[t1 t2 t3 t4]
snippets = %w[n1 n2 n3 n4]
urls     = %w[u1 u2 u3 u4]
sources  = %w[s1 s2 s3 s4]

pp titles.zip(snippets,urls,sources)
#=> [["t1", "n1", "u1", "s1"],
#=>  ["t2", "n2", "u2", "s2"],
#=>  ["t3", "n3", "u3", "s3"],
#=>  ["t4", "n4", "u4", "s4"]]
```

However, this might be dangerous. If there aren't the exact same number in each array—if one array is missing a source, for example—then they're going to wind up mis-associated:

```
titles   = %w[t1 t2 t3 t4]
snippets = %w[n1 n2 n3 n4]
urls     = %w[u1 u2 u3 u4]
sources  = %w[s1    s3 s4]

pp titles.zip(snippets,urls,sources)
#=> [["t1", "n1", "u1", "s1"],
#=>  ["t2", "n2", "u2", "s3"],
#=>  ["t3", "n3", "u3", "s4"],
#=>  ["t4", "n4", "u4", nil]]
```

Better to do what @pguardiario suggests: find each news result and then map that to its component pieces. Written more tersely:

```
parts = %w[Title Snippet Url Source]
all = doc.css("NewsResult").map{ |nr| parts.map{ |part| nr.at(part).text } }
```

This will give you an array of four-valued arrays, where `[0]` is the title's text, `[1]` is the snippet's, and so on:

```
all.each do |title,snippet,url,source|
  puts "Title: #{title} @ #{url} came from #{source}"
end
```

If you want a more usable construct, I'd personally create a Hash, so that I am not accessing values by magic index:

```
results = doc.css("NewsResult").map do |result|
  Hash[ parts.map{ |part| [part.downcase.to_sym, result.at(part).text] } ]
end

#…later…
results.each do |result|
  puts "Title: #{result[:title]} @ #{result[:url]} came from #{result[:source]}"
end
```